# Default application in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, configuration

Newbie question.

I installed Tomcat on my Ubuntu box and have it working, but I am having trouble understanding the docBase context (and, I guess, what contexts in general refer to).

I am using a different `CATALINA_BASE` = `~/dev/tomcat`, with my webapps directory etc underneath that. I placed the line

```
<Context path="" docBase="/home/.../tomcat/webapps"/>
```

in the server.xml file; I think this is what tells Tomcat where to look for its directories. But the tutorial I am reading implies (nay, it says) that I should place the line

```
<Context path="" docBase="/home/.../tomcat/webapps/ROOT"/>
```

in the server.xml file.

Is that correct? If so, what do these two lines do? (If there is a piece of documentation somewhere that clearly explains all of this, please just refer me to it, but I can't find one - the key word being clear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A context is more or less a "webapp context". It describes what is deploy and where / how to access it. The `docBase` is the location of the war, and the `path` the endpoint url.

It MUST be unique on a server.

Usually ROOT is deploy on myserver:8080/ (path= "") and mywebapp on myserver:8080/uhuh (path = "uhuh")

By default, if you don't specify a `path` tomcat deploys the application and set the path to the war name.

The `Context` directives are in the `Host` directive to override the default behaviour. The `Host` has the `appBase` attribute. This attribute declares where to find additional war to deploy. Normally, they are automatically deployed on tc start up with default settings.

HIH

Comment: I think I understand. But I have a subdirectory "test" in my webapps directory that I'm using to just figure stuff out, and no corresponding Context for that subdirectory. Yet localhost:8080/test/stuff works as I'd expect (after appropriate web.xml edits). So, at least for things deployed under my webapps directory, do I need a Context? (I see how it is needed for things deployed elsewhere). Thanks for the response.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the default behaviour (mapping /webapps/test to test, auto reload, ...) then no. In fact, tomcat will create silently a Context for you. Otherwise you'll need to create a Context in the server.xml to overwrite the basic configuration.